# Let $G$ be a finite simple non abelian group and $\{1\}\neq H\le G$ be such that $\vert C_{G}(H)\vert=\vert G:H \vert$. Then $H=G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a finite simple non abelian group and $\{1\}\neq H\leq G$ be such that $\vert C_{G}(H)\vert=\vert G:H \vert$. Show that $H=G$.

I can find only $[G,G]=G$ and $Z(G)=\{1\}$ and if $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, then $G \hookrightarrow S_{\vert G:H\vert}$. Can't bring $C_G(H)$ into the picture. Can anyone please provide a hint to think about it?

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for pointing out those possibilities. I have slightly modified the question.

Comment: Where does the question come from?

Comment: I was looking at excercise of Martin Issacs book on group theory. This question looks interesting to me.

Comment: Which exercise? It can help to know which section it is in.

Comment: This can be solved by applying the Chermak-Delgado measure.

Comment: I was looking at the statement for 20 minutes and could make no progress. I am curious if this question can be answered without appealing to the Chermak-Delgado measure/subgroup.

Comment: Could we use the class equation somehow?

Comment: @DerekHolt It is problem number $1.G.3.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See I.M. Isaacs, *Finite Group Theory*, chapter 1G. 
If $G$ is abelian, $|G| = |H||C_G(H)| = |H||G|$, so $H = 1$.
So we may assume $G$ to be non-abelian.
Let $M$ be the Chermak-Delgado subgroup of $G$. Then $M \lt G$ since $M$ is abelian and $G$ is not.
And, $M = 1$, since $M$ is normal and $G$ is simple. Consequently $m_G(M) = |G| = m_G(H)$, so $H \in \mathcal{L}(G)$.
Assuming $H \lt G$, we will show $H = 1$. Indeed, by Problem 1G.2 there is a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that
$H \subseteq N \lt G$. But $G$ is simple, so $N = 1$. Hence $H = 1$.